# Add new column to ndarray of inverted binary values | NumPy Array Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I want to append a second column to an ndarray, containing the opposite binary value.

Take this ndarray of n rows and 1 column, containing binary values:

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [1]]
```

I want to have a for loop that yields this output:

```
[[0,1]
 [1,0]
 [0,1]
 [1,0]]
```

Accessing the nested ndarray, adding the opposite: either `1` or `0`.

Note: `append()`, `insert()` etc. do not work as this is a multi-dimensional array. Not a list (hence many `[]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
np.concatenate([a,1-a], axis=1)
```

Or

```
np.hstack([a,1-a])
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this by taking a `not` gate operation on the binary values to change 0 to 1 and vice versa. Then you can horizontally stack the 2 arrays `a` and `not a` into a (4,2) array -

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0],[1],[0],[1]])
b = np.logical_not(a).astype(int)

np.hstack([a,b])
```

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you. You did it so fast like it was nothing haha

Comment: Thanks, Quang Hoang did it faster than me :). Do check his approaches as well. They would help you explore how NumPy works as well (broadcasting using `1-a` for example)